# What is the effect of creating a folder, is it an automatic namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a two part question.

**Question 1.**

I've always thought a folder was an automatic namespace, but I just went back and refactored some code and ended up with something like this:

- a folder named formatter
- a file formatter.rb that contained references to all of the files within the folder
- a formatter/formatter.rb file that has a class Formatter, with no reference to the namespace
- 3 other classes that inherit from class Formatter: FooFormatter, BarFormatter, BazFormatter, with no reference to the namespace
- one ActionFormatter class that does not inherit from class Formatter, and has no reference to the namespace

What surprised me was that I didn't need to create namespaces around each of the file like I have in the past.  Like:

```
Module Formatter
  Class ActionFormatter
```

Is this because the Module Formatter is implied by being in this folder?  I still have to reference it as Formatter::ActionFormatter when it is called.  But why doesn't FooFormatter need this reference.

**Question 2.**

Everything seems to work, but I get this warning:

warning: toplevel constant FormatAction referenced by Formatter::FormatAction on the line where I have

```
@formatter = Formatter::ActionFormatter
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a folder does not define a namespace all by itself. The rails autoloading mechanism though, tries to load the definition for a non existint constant A::B::C within a/b/c.rb. If you define another constant there (especially without a namespace), it will exist (without namespace). If there is both, a toplevel constant and a namespaced constant with the same name and you access this constant from within the namespace, you get the above warning.

When you go with rails, you have to define namespaced constants with their namespace, like this: class A::B::C < D. Also, as far as I know, inheritance does not influence namespacing in any way.

Comment: So you're saying the autoloading mechanism of A::B is separate from what a namespace is.  Even though they are referred to with the same syntax?  I removed the reference to Formatter/ActionFormatter.rb and the warning went away.  But now I'm wondering if ActionFormatter is namespaced, or what I'm losing by not having it namespaced.

Comment: It's not separate, rails looks for the file according to namespacing conventions in order to find the definition for a constant. If your constant is not namespaced within that file, rails will take it (load it's definition) anyway. Whether to namespace or not is a question of taste. In general, constants which serve a common purpose, should be put into a namespace together. Or, if you wanted to write a class "ActiveSupport", you would namespace it in order not to mess up toplevel ActiveSupport.

Comment: One advice: Take a look into the code of some rubygems on github to understand how and why they structured code in folders corresponding to the namespaces/modules they use.

Comment: @mosch You might be able to answer a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116848/rails-not-using-correct-constant-when-class-namespaced-gives-warning-toplevel

Answer (score 0):

@moritz is correct, just a little addition for future searchers.

## GOTCHAS

Can't load namespaced controllers

Errors:

```
warning: toplevel constant Finance referenced by Member::Finance
```

OR

```
uninitialized constant Finance
```

Cause:

a namespaced controller / helper which is listed BEFORE it's dependency. e.g. ll member/finance/ bank_batches_controller.rb base_controller.rb

Fix:

make this the first line of the dependent:

`require_dependency "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/controllers/member/finance/base_controller"`

Requiring the dependent file before attempting to load the class. 
(Yes, this goes before `class ...`)